# how to set order status as 'complete' in magento

Tags: magento

how do i set order status as 'complete' manually.

I am using the following code, but its giving error saying, 
**The Order State 'complete' must not be set manually.**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->save();
```

Answer (score 24):

i found a solution for my self,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $order->setData('state', "complete");
        $order->setStatus("complete");       
        $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
        $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order->save();
```

Comment: Careful: this will lead to the customer being notified by email - if you want the notification to be skipped, you must use setIsCustomerNotified(null) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310094/how-to-update-magento-order-status-without-triggering-notification-email/34310095

Answer (score 11):

well, the actual way to make order state `COMPLETE` is to create `invoice` and `shipment`, after which the order state auto gets `COMPLETE` state. Like:

```
//create invoice for the order
$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice()
                   ->setTransactionId($order->getId())
                   ->addComment("Invoice created from cron job.")
                   ->register()
                   ->pay();

$transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                            ->addObject($invoice)
                            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transaction_save->save();
//now create shipment
//after creation of shipment, the order auto gets status COMPLETE
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
if( $shipment ) {
     $shipment->register();
     $order->setIsInProcess(true);

     $transaction_save = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                ->addObject($shipment)
                                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                                ->save();
}
```

Comment: There are lots of q/a about this on different SO sites, this was the only one I could get to work. Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, in terms of the workflow. But if that fails (sometimes there is a problem creating a shipment) then you may need to use user2629419's answer.

Answer (score 0):

kindly change object manager to di

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
            $order = $orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $order->setState('awaiting_stock');
            $order->setStatus('awaiting_stock');
            $orderRepository->save($order);
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Set order status programmatically:**

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-order-status-programmatically/

> ```
> change order status to 'Completed'
> ```

```
$orderIncrementId = YOUR_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

 $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE,true)->save();
```