# How to update Magento order status without triggering notification email?

Tags: magento

After some integration issues with Magento, I need to update the status and state of a few orders. However, since these updates are not really relevant for the customer, I **do not want the system to send order notification e-mails** for each order update in this case.

What does not work:

```
$historyItem = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('some comment', 'complete');
$historyItem->setIsVisibleOnFront(false);
$historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
$historyItem->save();
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History`, you can see that the `setIsCustomerNotified` method suppresses notification if you provide either parameter `null` or the value of the constant `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History::CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION_NOT_APPLICABLE`. Confusingly, using `false` will lead to the notification being sent.

### Updating Magento Order Status without Sending Notification E-Mail to Customer

This code block works - revise order status, adding a comment that is visible only on the backend and will not trigger a notification e-mail to the client:

```
$historyItem = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('some comment', 'complete');
$historyItem->setIsVisibleOnFront(false);
$historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History::CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION_NOT_APPLICABLE);
$historyItem->save();
$order->save();
```